# Removing specific value from LinkedHashMap containing key <String> and value LinkedList<String>

Tags: java, list, linked-list, hashmap

I have run into a headscratcher where I know what's wrong, but can't put it in code. I'm currently working on a card deck where I'd like to remove a specific card suit from a card rank in a `LinkedHashMap`. I've searched everywhere of a specific solution to my very specific problem, but am unable to find one.
I've tried using entrySet, an iterator and a logic solution, but the `remove()` operation seems to delete all records of a `value` disregarding the `key`.
Examples below demonstrates my attempts to remove 5 of hearts.

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Map;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Deck deck = new Deck();
        System.out.println(deck.deck);

        //ENTRYSET
        for (Map.Entry<String, LinkedList<String>> entry : deck.deck.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(entry.getValue());
            System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            if (entry.getKey().contains("5")) {
                if (entry.getValue().contains("Hearts")) {
                    entry.getValue().remove("Hearts");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(deck.deck);

        //LOGIC SOLUTION
        if (! deck.deck.get("5").isEmpty()) {
            deck.deck.get("King").remove("Hearts");
        }

        //ITERATOR
        for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, LinkedList<String>>> it = deck.deck.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext(); ) {
            Map.Entry<String, LinkedList<String>> entry = it.next();
            LinkedList<String> list = entry.getValue();
            System.out.println(list);
            if (entry.getKey().equals("5")) {


                for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
                    if (list.get(i).equals("Hearts")) {
                        list.remove(i);
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if (list.isEmpty())
                    it.remove();
            }
        }
        System.out.println(deck.deck);
    }
}
```

Output entrySet:

```
{2=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 3=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 4=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 5=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 6=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 7=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 8=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 9=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 10=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], Jack=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], Queen=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], King=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], Ace=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades]}
[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades]
2
[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades]
3
[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades]
4
[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades]
5
{2=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 3=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 4=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 5=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 6=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 7=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 8=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 9=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 10=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], Jack=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], Queen=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], King=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], Ace=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades]}
```

Output Logic solution:

```
{2=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 3=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 4=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 5=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 6=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 7=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 8=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 9=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 10=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], Jack=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], Queen=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], King=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], Ace=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades]}
{2=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 3=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 4=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 5=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 6=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 7=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 8=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 9=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 10=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], Jack=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], Queen=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], King=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], Ace=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades]}
```

Output Iterator:

```
{2=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 3=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 4=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 5=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 6=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 7=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 8=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 9=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 10=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], Jack=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], Queen=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], King=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], Ace=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades]}
[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades]
[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades]
[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades]
[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades]
[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades]
[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades]
[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades]
[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades]
[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades]
[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades]
[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades]
[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades]
[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades]
{2=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 3=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 4=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 5=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 6=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 7=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 8=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 9=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 10=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], Jack=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], Queen=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], King=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], Ace=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades]}
```

What I would like the map to contain:

```
{2=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 3=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 4=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 5=[Clubs, Diamonds, Spades], 6=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 7=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 8=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 9=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], 10=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], Jack=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], Queen=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], King=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades], Ace=[Clubs, Diamonds, Hearts, Spades]}
```

So how would I specifiy the key of which to remove the suit? I wish not to remove all instances of "Hearts" (like in this example). Help and clues are very much appreciated!

**EDIT:**

Population of the suits made keys point to only one list in memory in the map.

Before:

```
public Deck() {
        for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
            deck.put(String.valueOf(i), suits));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            deck.put(highRank.get(i), suits));
        }

    }
```

After:

```
public Deck() {
        for (int i = 2; i <= 10; i++) {
            deck.put(String.valueOf(i), new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList("Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades")));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
            deck.put(highRank.get(i), new LinkedList<String>(Arrays.asList("Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades")));
        }

    }
```

Comment: so remove from `Deck` - OK, but what on earth is `Deck` ?

Comment: My logic solution applies to this attempt. Deck is just an object class of a card deck, where I can perform operations of a Map data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is at the map population, not when deleting:

If you have the following:

```
Map<String, List> myMap = ...
List<String> myList = ...
myMap.put("1", myList);
myMap.put("2", myList);
```

Then when you remove you'll be removing from both map entries at the same time:

```
myMap.get("1").remove("Hearts");  // removes both from myMap.get("1") and MyMap.get("2")
```

Comment: Although this isn't an answer, the hint was enough to make me fully understand the situation. I guess your explaination suggests what a map is originally used for, to map keys to destinations in memory (which in my situation pointed to the same list in memory). As soon as I realised this I new that my population of the map needed keys to point to unique lists, rather than one list. The solution was rather simple! Thank you!